# How to initialize weights in Flux.jl

Tags: julia, flux.jl

I want to initialize some weights and bias for a specific layer in my model. How is this possible in `Flux.jl`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the layer functions such as `Dense` and `Conv` take in the weight and bias. You can see the function definition of each by doing `? Dense` or `? Conv` which would reveal that for example, the Dense function can be simple called with weights and bars by doing: `Dense(W::AbstractMatrix, [bias, σ])` and for the `Conv` function, something like this:

```
  julia> weight = rand(3, 4, 5);
  
  julia> bias = zeros(5);
  
  julia> c1 = Conv(weight, bias, sigmoid)  # expects 1 spatial dimension
  Conv((3,), 4=>5, σ)
```

where `sigmoid` is syntactical sugar for the sigmoid function, often denoted as `σ()`.